# Is is possible to view the contents of SAS Library in SQL script format?

Tags: sas

I am wondering if it is possible to check the content of library dataset in SQL script format.
Currently I just know how to view the content of library in default format.

```
PROC CONTENTS data = libref._ALL_ NODS;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

See SASHELP.VSCOLUMN when you run DESCRIBE on it you will that they are derived from datasets in the library DICTIONARY. As you can see DICTIONARY has an to long libref and can only be accessed from PROC SQL. For more info look here:
https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi30/070-30.pdf